# INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE multiple Tags input using INNERJOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

from a form like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $tags = $_POST['tags'];
 ?>
<form method="post">
     <select name="tags" multiple>
          <option>PHP</option>
          <option>HTML</option>
          <option>CSS</option>
     </select>
<button type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

tables:

```
          [     POSTS     ]  [     TAGS   ]  [       POSTS_TAGS       ]
          | id |   title  |  | id |  name |  | id |  post_id |tage_id |
          |----|----------|  |----|-------|  |----|----------|--------|
          | 1  |   PHP7   |  | 1  | PHP   |  | 1  |     1    |    1   |
          | 2  |   HTML   |  | 2  | HTML  |  | 2  |     1    |    2   |
          | 3  |   CSS3   |  | 3  | CSS   |  | 3  |     1    |    3   |
          _________________  ______________  | 4  |     2    |    2   |
                                             | 5  |     2    |    3   |
                                             | 6  |     3    |    3   |
                                             __________________________
```

How can i insert, update, delete all the `options` inside the POSTS_TAGS table? i maybe can understand how to insert it using implode and explode, But updating and deleting , Can't figure out how to do that efficeinly.

Comment: you already have a parse error btw.

Comment: You may need multiple query statements to insert, update and delete data sets you would select with joins. So if you are creating a new post you need to execute an insert for posts before insert into posts_tags so you can get the new id for the post entry

Comment: @M31 So do i make two `insert` statement to `insert` the post into `POSTS` and the `post_id` into the `POSTS_TAGS?` Is inserting into two tables using 1 query is good or 2 queries is better?

Comment: You can create one query which contains two insert statements and use something like LAST_INSERT_ID() in the second insert statement to get the post id value. If you can confirm you are using php to handle the form data and MySQL database I can write an answer with more specific recommendations

Comment: @M31 i don't use MySQL exactly, But right now i use phpmyadmin and i don't know If it is natural for everyone to move to MySQL after releasing their website for better Database or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you mentioned you were using phpMyAdmin, which is a user interface for MySQL database. If you are trying to manipulate records in that database with your form you will need to submit it to a php script which will run the query you are looking for. I updated your form to include the post title and have action send the data to submit.php. You could also submit the form in other ways but for this example I'll stick with the HTML default:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
     <input type="text" name="title">
     <select name="tags" multiple>
          <option value="1">PHP</option>
          <option value="2">HTML</option>
          <option value="3">CSS</option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

In submit.php you will handle the data from the form and run your sql query.

```
<?php
      //connect to mysql 
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db_name");
      //collect data from form
      $tags = explode(",",$_POST['tags']);
      $title = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['title']);
      //create sql statements
      $sql = "INSERT INTO Posts (title) VALUES ('$title'); SET @pid = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
      // add insert statement for each selected tag
      foreach($tags as $tag){
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO Posts_Tags (post_id,tag_id) VALUES(@pid,".mysqli_escape_string($tag).");";
      }
      // Run the complete query
      $result = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
      if($result){
           //success
      }else{
           //error
      }
 ?>
```

This code is meant to create and execute a query with two or more insert statements which will add the new post and associate the correct tags. You can test the sql using phpMyAdmin which will look like the below:

```
INSERT INTO Posts (title) VALUES ('Post Title');
SET @pid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Posts_Tags (post_id,tag_id) VALUES(@pid,1);
INSERT INTO Posts_Tags (post_id,tag_id) VALUES(@pid,2);
```

You can do something similar to process updates and deletes, however in the case of update queries some additional logic will be required to test for records in Posts_Tags which need to be deleted because the association was removed. The delete would be pretty straight forward:

```
DELETE FROM Posts WHERE id = 1; DELETE FROM Posts_Tags WHERE post_id = 1;
```

You would only need the post id to be submitted from your delete form to be able to create the query. I hope this helps